# How can I shift my label up and down on UIswitch on and off?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uiswitch

I have a UIswitch and when it is on I want to present a view below it and shift all the other views down. Similarly when the switch is off , the view should disappear rearranging all the views as before.

```
  @objc func switchValueDidChange(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    if sender == fuelSwitch{
        if (sender.isOn == true){
            // show fuel view
            print("on")
            fuelRequiredView?.isHidden = false
            topConstraint = layoutConstraints.setTopMargin(isOverloadedLabel, attribute1: .topMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: fuelRequiredView, attribute2: .topMargin, multiplier: 2.0, constant: 0)
            contentView?.addConstraint(topConstraint!)
            topConstraint = layoutConstraints.setTopMargin(overloadedSwitch, attribute1: .topMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: fuelRequiredView, attribute2: .topMargin, multiplier: 2.0, constant: 0)
            contentView?.addConstraint(topConstraint!)

        }
        else{
            // hide fuel view
            print("off")
            fuelRequiredView?.isHidden = true
            topConstraint = layoutConstraints.setTopMargin(isOverloadedLabel, attribute1: .topMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute2: .topMargin, multiplier: 2.4, constant: 0)
            contentView?.addConstraint(topConstraint!)
            topConstraint = layoutConstraints.setTopMargin(overloadedSwitch, attribute1: .topMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute2: .topMargin, multiplier: 2.4, constant: 0)
            contentView?.addConstraint(topConstraint!)
        }
    }
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzIdP.jpg)

Comment: use UIStackView for that purpose.

Comment: @Vishal16 if you could just provide a short working code it would be easy to understand. :)

Comment: Are you using a storyboard or adding views programmatically?

Comment: programmatically. I don't use storyboard

Comment: Check my answer, Please upvote and accept it. If it may help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may help you. Please follow this points:

- Add `UIScrollView` to your `UIViewController` in storyboard or XIB.
- Initiate an `NSMutableArray` name it `arrViews` gets server response and adds view in the array.
- Initialise `UIStackView`pass `arrView` array in the init method.
- After that `UIStackView` will be added subview of `UIScrollView`.
- Add constraint programmatically to `UIStackView`. That's it.

  ```
  let arrViews =  createSubViews(view)
  let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: arrViews)
  stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  stackView.axis = .vertical
  stackView.spacing = 16
  stackView.distribution = .fill
  self.scrollView.addSubview(stackView)

  //constraints

  let leading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.scrollView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
  self.scrollView.addConstraint(leading)
  let trailing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.scrollView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
  self.scrollView.addConstraint(trailing)
  let top = NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.scrollView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
  self.scrollView.addConstraint(top)

  let bottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.scrollView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
  self.scrollView.addConstraint(bottom)

  let equalWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.scrollView, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

  self.scrollView.addConstraint(equalWidth)


  leading.isActive = true
  trailing.isActive = true
  top.isActive = true
  bottom.isActive = true
  equalWidth.isActive = true
  ```

After that when you click on the switch get a view from an array of views and hide it all other views automatically rearranged.

```
@objc func switchValueDidChange(_ sender: UISwitch) {
if sender == fuelSwitch{
      let fuelRequiredView = arrViews[index] // get index of fuelRequiredView
    if (sender.isOn == true){
        // show fuel view
        print("on")
        fuelRequiredView?.isHidden = false
    }
    else{
        // hide fuel view
        print("off")
        fuelRequiredView?.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you. Happy coding :)

Comment: Don't I need to add constraints for views? Didn't get this let arrViews =  createSubViews(view)

Comment: are you using XIB? so you can assign constraints to sub-views of that xib and no need to assign constraint to individual view if it has equal spacing.

Comment: I have added an image above. Please refer to that image. When the switch for fuel required is on the view should appear below it shifting the is overloaded view and its switch below.

Comment: so you can make 3 views add a label and switch as a subview of the other two views (Fuel required or is overloaded) also add constraints programmatically to subviews and then add all the 3 views to UIstackView. That's it.

Comment: The first view contains fuel label and switch as subviews. The second view contains overloaded label and switch as subviews. What is the third view? and What about the constraints for these views?

Comment: the third view will be your toggle view which will be show/hide when you clicked on fuel required switch. You need to add it to subview after fuel required view and make it hidden or visible as you like.

Comment: What is the third view? Please read your question first you have just specified you need to show/hide a view?

Comment: I am getting layout constraint exception. The views need to have some constraint before setting constraints for its subviews.

Comment: I think you are missing something. Do I need to check your code?

Comment: yes. How can I give you the code. Please let me know

Comment: Upload it to google drive or drop-Box and make a shareable link. You can comment that link here. Or also you can try to figure out that issue with yourself you just need to make an array of view.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_ZBEzEdJs9VvOIXlOgPIBaj2qNABD4LVtdhGu6zr6aw Here is the link